# How to use Nested ng-repeat to repeat table columns dynamically?

Tags: angularjs, nested

I want to make dynamic columns of a table and create a new object to save it in mongoDb.

I have first Array of Student as:

```
students = [{id: "1", name: "abc"},{id: "2", name: "def"},{id: "3", name: "hij"}]
```

and have second Array of Subjects as:

```
subjects = [{sName: "maths"},{sName: "science"}]
```

**Here is the HTML**

```
<div ng-app='t' ng-controller='test'>
    <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th ng-repeat="subject in subjects">{{subject.sName}}</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in finalData track by $index">
            <th><input type="text" ng-model="row.rollNo"/></th>
            <th><input type="text" ng-model="row.fullName"></th>
            <th ng-repeat="subject in subjects"><input type="text" ng-model="row.marks"></th>
            <th>
      <button ng-click="action($index)">
        add/remove
      </button></th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

**Here is the Controller**

```
(function(){

    var app = angular.module('t', []);

    app.controller('test', 
      [
          '$scope', 
          function($scope)                            
          {
            $scope.students = [{id: "1", name: "abc"},{id: "2", name: "def"},{id: "3", name: "hij"}]

            $scope.subjects = [{sName: "maths"},{sName: "science"}]
            $scope.finalData = new Array();
            $scope.finalData.push({
                icon : false
            });

            $scope.action=function(index){
                if(index ==  $scope.finalData.length-1){
                     $scope.finalData[index].icon = true;

                     $scope.finalData.push({
                        icon : false
                    });

                }else{
                         $scope.finalData.splice(index, 1);
                }
            };

            }
      ]);

})();
```

The Output Looks like this.[image: 8]

The marks columns are repeating similar values. But i want one single finalObject to save my data.

Here is the jsFiddle of my problem **https://jsfiddle.net/g8tn71tr/**

Answer (score 1):

The row subjects refer to the same NgModel `row.marks` which makes them have the same value.

You can solve it by making the ng-model refer to each of the subjects `ng-model="row.marks[subject.sName]"`. This will result in that row.marks will become an object where each subject will be a key and the model will be in its value

```js
(function(){

    var app = angular.module('t', []);

    app.controller('test', 
      [
          '$scope', 
          function($scope)                            
          {
            $scope.students = [{id: "1", name: "abc"},{id: "2", name: "def"},{id: "3", name: "hij"}]

            $scope.subjects = [{sName: "maths"},{sName: "science"}]
            $scope.finalData = new Array();
            $scope.finalData.push({
                icon : false
            });

            $scope.action=function(index){
            console.clear();
            console.log($scope.finalData[index]);
                if(index ==  $scope.finalData.length-1){
                     $scope.finalData[index].icon = true;

                     $scope.finalData.push({
                        icon : false
                    });

                }else{
                         $scope.finalData.splice(index, 1);
                }
            };

            }
      ]);

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='t' ng-controller='test'>
    <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th ng-repeat="subject in subjects">{{subject.sName}}</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in finalData track by $index">
            <th><input type="text" ng-model="row.rollNo"/></th>
            <th><input type="text" ng-model="row.fullName"></th>
            <th ng-repeat="subject in subjects"><input type="text" ng-model="row.marks[subject.sName]"></th>
            <th>
      <button ng-click="action($index)">
        add/remove
      </button></th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```